# At what point does Moshe relay G-d's commandments to B'nai Yisra'el?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, mesorah-tradition

I'm asking this as a general question. We do see in a few places that G-d speaks to Moshe and then, the Torah says something like, "Moshe told this to B'nai Yisra'el".

But, in numerous other places (seems common in the book of Vayikra, esp.) a paragraph begins וידבר ה אל משה לאמור (G-d spoke to Moshe to say..)

At what point did Moshe relay a set of commandments to the people? Should we assume that everything between one set of saying וידבר ה אל משה לאמור until its next appearance was said, or is there some other rule / method as to how to calculate this?

*Assist with tagging, please*

Comment: We should probably differentiate between two types of directions: 1. General Mitzvos (613) 2. On-time Mitzvos (see Rambam) 3. General Behavioral directions (like "let them go, let them park"). It is also unclear by Meforshim, whether Moses was continuously writing those commandments as parts of Torah or not, as it contradicts the idea of getting Torah as whole. **If yes** - what did the Torah from Sinay contain, **if no** - what was the pint in commanding what's already been given?

Comment: Hi @AlBerko. Some good questions. I don't think the Torah was given as a whole. I'm not sure if there's anyone who says that. It had to be written in sections, and, it's also clear that it wasn't written "sequentially" as events happened. As for the last question, I was hesitant to include in my own question as to when *Torah B'al Peh* (Oral law) was given and how that fits into the chronology. I don't want to "overload" my question, here, at least, not yet.

Comment: Exactly, anyway you look at it, it looks improbable. But I don't give up, even if I need to sacrifice some "truths". THe easiest to loose is the "form of Torah", i.g. the text. For example, some may say a person and his DNA are the same, but for us they are not. So my solution is to say that there were a lot of "blueprints of the Torah" each one on a more detailed level. So Moses got it on a "DNA" level, but he didn't know how it will unfold, and it could unfold in myriads of different ways.

Comment: ... (contd) For example Korah might be right, the Calf might be useful etc. This could explain why Moses hesitated so much almost in every dispute, and sometimes "misinterpret" the situation altogether. This also explains a lot of phenomena ((like 600K letters) and conciliates contradictions in interpretations (some explain it by תואר and some by פועל).